# How to call backing bean method from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsf

I want to use a jquery charts in my jsf project to do some statistics, how can I call Java methods (from managedbesn) in my jquery function ?
this is my jquery function to show bar chart

var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

```
var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
```

i want to fill in the field label (labels :["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"])   with data calling from java method for example:

public list getmonths(){--------code-------}

Comment: Post what you have tried, so that we can understand how you wanna make it.

Comment: most certainly it might include ajax

Comment: But I don't understand what is the problem in doing that. @ArunPJohny

Comment: Extremely a lot of starters fail to realize that JSF is in the context of this kind of questions merely a HTML/CSS/JS code generator. Thus, all you have to do is just writing JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired JS output. E.g. `<script>var foo = '#{bean.foo}';</script>`. Are you aware of this, bilel? If so, then please reframe the question to ask a more specific question and elaborate why this approach is insuitable.

Comment: good approach BalusC thxs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your maneged bean

```
  List<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();
  public List<String> getMonths(){
    if(months.isEmpty()) {
      months.add("January");
      months.add("February");
      months.add("March");
      months.add("April");
    }
    return months;
  }
```

Then access the list as below in your xhtml page.

```
var barChartData = {labels : ["#{MyBean.months.get(0)}","#{MyBean.months.get(1)}","#{MyBean.months.get(2)}","#{MyBean.months.get(3)}"]}
```